# category filter, how do I display only the featured ones instead of displaying all

Tags: javascript

I'm studying javascript and in the first page I would like to show the items that has an id of feature rather than showing all items at the front. Currently this is the code,

```
const categoryTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.category-title');
console.log(categoryTitle);
const allCategoryPosts = document.querySelectorAll('.all');
console.log(categoryTitle);

for(let i = 0; i < categoryTitle.length; i++){
    categoryTitle[i].addEventListener('click', filterPosts.bind(this, categoryTitle[i]));
}

function filterPosts(item){
    changeActivePosition(item);
    for(let i = 0; i < allCategoryPosts.length; i++){
        if(allCategoryPosts[i].classList.contains(item.attributes.id.value)){
            allCategoryPosts[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            allCategoryPosts[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function changeActivePosition(activeItem){
    for(let i = 0; i < categoryTitle.length; i++){
        categoryTitle[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    activeItem.classList.add('active');
};
console.log("hello");
```

right now I have a list of items that have a class name of all + whatever the category that item belongs to. I tried removing the class name "all" from the ones that I don't want to display but it's not ding the job.

Comment: `item.attributes.id.value` should just be `item.value` or `item.id`. It's hard to be sure without seeing the HTML of the categories.

Comment: Where are you calling the filterPosts function ? Also it would be useful to see how is formatted an `item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP doesn't have any HTML posted, so it's impossible to analyze and resolve a specific problem. The answer doesn't show what's wrong with the OP's code nor is it an improved version. The answer uses code that does what the OP code is supposed to do which is to filter tags.

Avoid adding multiple eventListeners that basically do the same thing for different tags. Registering a single eventListener to a parent tag of multiple tags is much more efficient, see [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Utility function that logs data to the console.
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// Reference the <form>
const search = document.forms.search;
// Declare "status"
let status;
// An array of strings representing the #ids of each checked checkbox.
let activeFilters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
// A NodeList of each <label> within #categories.
let allCategories = document.querySelectorAll("#categories label");

// Register "change" event to the <form> 
search.onchange = filterCategories;

// All event handlers pass the event object by default.
function filterCategories(event) {
  // Reference the tag changed by a user.
  const switched = event.target;

  // If the tag the user changed is an <input> within #filter...
  if (switched.matches("#filters input")) {
    // ...and if it is checked...
    if (switched.checked) {
      // ...add it's #id to the activeFilters array...
      activeFilters.push(switched.id);
      // ...then add className "active" to it's parent <label>...
      switched.parentElement.classList.add("active");
      // ...assign "active" to status...
      status = "active";
      // ...otherwise...
    } else {
      // ...remove the corresponding #id in the activeFilters array...
      activeFilters.splice(activeFilters.indexOf(switched.id), 1);
      // ...then remove className "active" from parent <label>...
      switched.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
      // ...assign "inactive" to status...
      status = "inactive";
    }
    /* Log runtime data to the console. 
    console.clear();
    log(`activeFilters = [${activeFilters}]`);
    log(`Filter ${switched.id} is ${status}.`);
    //*/
    // Hide all <label> in #categorey
    allCategories.forEach(cat => cat.classList.add("hide"));
    // For each #id in activeFilter array...
    activeFilters.forEach(act => {
      // ...iterate through allCategories array...
      allCategories.forEach(cat => {
        /* ...if a className of a <label> in #categorey 
        matches #id of current <input> #id... */
        if (cat.classList.contains(act)) {
          // ...show the <label>
          cat.classList.remove("hide");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 96vw;
}

#filters {
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#filters label {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#categories .A,
.A.active {
  color: #fc0;
  background: #000;
  border-color: #fc0
}

#categories .B,
.B.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0cf;
  border-color: #fff
}

#categories .C,
.C.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f00;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

#categories .D,
.D.active {
  color: #0cf;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #0cf
}

#categories .E,
.E.active {
  color: #000;
  background: #fc0;
  border-color: #000
}

#categories label {
  width: 4.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem
}

#categories label:before {
  content: attr(class);
}

#categories .hide {
  display: none;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  color: lime;
  background: black;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="search">
  <fieldset id="filters">
    <legend>Filters</legend>
    <!-- 
      Each checkbox is nested in a <label> hidden.
      Initially, each <label> has className "active" and each 
      checkbox is checked.
    -->
    <label class="A active">A<input id="A" type="checkbox" hidden checked></label>
    <label class="B active">B<input id="B" type="checkbox" hidden checked></label>
    <label class="C active">C<input id="C" type="checkbox" hidden checked></label>
    <label class="D active">D<input id="D" type="checkbox" hidden checked></label>
    <label class="E active">E<input id="E" type="checkbox" hidden checked></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="categories">
    <legend>Categories</legend>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="B"></label>
    <label class="A"></label>
    <label class="C"></label>
    <label class="E"></label>
    <label class="D"></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```